# password checker not working as expected

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a test to check the level of security of a password. The problem is when the regex that have been used are stored in the array 'comprobaciones', sometimes a single regex is saved more than once, so when I check the length of the array 'comprobaciones' me back as possible outputs 1, 2 , 4, 8, and 16. How could I solve it for the length of the array 'comprobaciones' has got like outputs 1,2,3,4 and 5? What am I doing wrong? Help, thanks.

is it possible a problem in any 
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fJgse/)

JAVASCRIPT

```
var compMay = /[A-ZÑ]/;
var compMin = /[a-zñ]/;
var compNum = /(?=.*\d)/;
var compCarEsp = /[!@#$%^&*(){}[\]<>+¿¡?/|.:;_-]/;
var compLong = /^.{8,}$/;
var seguridadPass = []; 
seguridadPass.push(compMin,compMay,compNum,compCarEsp,compLong);

function pintaValidar(numComp){


    if(numComp==1){
        $('#porcentaje').removeClass();
        $('#porcentaje').addClass('segurRojo');
        $('#porcentaje').css('width', '20%');
    }
    if(numComp==2){
        $('#porcentaje').removeClass();
        $('#porcentaje').addClass('segurRojo');
        $('#porcentaje').css('width', '40%');
    }
    if(numComp==4){
        $('#porcentaje').removeClass();
        $('#porcentaje').addClass('segurVerde');
        $('#porcentaje').css('width', '60%');
    }
    if(numComp==8){
        $('#porcentaje').removeClass();
        $('#porcentaje').addClass('segurVerde');
        $('#porcentaje').css('width', '80%');
    }
    if(numComp==16){
        $('#porcentaje').removeClass();
        $('#porcentaje').addClass('segurVerde');
        $('#porcentaje').css('width', '100%');
    }
    comprobaciones = [];

}

$(document).ready(function(){

comprobaciones = []

$('#psd').keyup(function(e){

    var pass = $(this).val();
    if(pass!=''){
        for(i=0;i<seguridadPass.length;i++){
            if(seguridadPass[i].test(pass)){
                //alert(seguridadPass[i]);

                if(comprobaciones.length==0){
                    comprobaciones.push(seguridadPass[i]);
                }
                else{
                    for(j=0;j<comprobaciones.length;j++){
                        if(comprobaciones[j]!=seguridadPass[i]){
                            comprobaciones.push(seguridadPass[i]);  
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        var numComp = comprobaciones.length
        pintaValidar(numComp);
    }
    else{
        $('#porcentaje').removeClass();
        $('#puntos').html('');
        comprobaciones.splice(0,comprobaciones.length);
    }
});

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having 2 loops. This loops causes the error. You were adding all that was already inside the `comprobaciones` a second time into the `comprobaciones`. Therefor you got an increment of `*2`.

```
for(j=0;j<comprobaciones.length;j++){
    if(comprobaciones[j]!=seguridadPass[i]){
        comprobaciones.push(seguridadPass[i]);  
    }
}
```

The fix:

```
var contains = false;
for(j=0;j<comprobaciones.length;j++){
    if(comprobaciones[j]==seguridadPass[i]){
        contains = true;
    }
}
if( !contains ) {
    comprobaciones.push(seguridadPass[i]);
}
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/fJgse/1/)

Comment: That's just what I was about to post :-)